# homomorphic encryption function representation

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, function-evaluation

As it known, Homomorphic encryption can be used for privacy-preserving outsourced storage and computation. In various constructions, the computations are represented as either Boolean or arithmetic circuits and can use garbled circuits.

My problem is that I couldn't find explicit documentation on how to outsource the function for computation.
What are the possible and practical techniques to represent the function to be evaluated if we do not use a circuit.

Comment: Are you asking how to send all circuit to cloud?

Comment: Yes. I need to know if any circuit that represent a function is transferred to the Cloud for computation or just a description of it and the Cloud is the one who generate it.

Comment: actually, you just send your code via ssh, however for data you may prefer [FHE-AES](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/35332/18298)